# Elastic Search: How to format sum_bucket aggregation float output?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use Elastic Search for my Search Service and I use this JSON request for sum_bucket aggregation:

```
"from": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "aggregations": {
        "aggr": {
            "type": "term",
            "field": "type.keyword",
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
                "myAggr2.value": "desc"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "myAggr2": {
                    "type": "sum",
                    "field": "length"
                }
            }
        },
        "total_myAggr2": {
            "type": "sum_bucket",
            "buckets_path": "aggr>myAggr2"
        }
    },
    "types": [
        "cable"
    ]
}
```

In response I get this:

```
{
    "totalHits": 4,
    "tookInMillis": 1,
    "hits": [],
    "aggregations": {
        "total_myAggr2": {
            "value": "3.7600000000000002"
        },
        "aggr": {
            "sumOtherDocCount": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "cable",
                    "count": 4,
                    "aggregations": {
                        "myAggr2": {
                            "value": "3.7600000000000002"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is any possibility to format the output from `"3.7600000000000002"` to `"3.76"`? I found attribute **format** in ES docu but not for number formatting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question answered on [ES discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-format-sum-bucket-aggregation-float-output/293851), the **format** value is set according to Java DecimalFormat. In my case `format: "#.##"`

Comment: where do you supply the format key in the request body? Can you please share an example? I'm also stuck with the same problem

Comment: Here is my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74847945/elasticsearch-how-to-return-output-value-with-specific-number-of-decimal-point