# Elasticsearch: How to return output value with specific number of decimal point

Tags: elasticsearch

**Elasticsearch: 6.8.23**

I'm trying to return the output value of an aggregated column with a specified number of decimal points currently, it's returning output with 13 decimal points.
I've tried format in the query request but it's not working, Query Used:

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "must": [{
                "range": {}
                }
            }, {
                "terms": {}
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "composite_buckets": {
        "composite": {
            "sources": [{
                    "outputCol1": {
                        "terms": {
                            "missing_bucket": true,
                            "field": "col1",
                            "order": "asc"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "outputCol2": {
                        "terms": {
                            "missing_bucket": true,
                            "field": "col2",
                            "order": "asc"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "outputCol3": {
                        "terms": {
                            "value_type": "string",
                            "missing_bucket": true,
                            "script": {
                                "source": "1",
                                "lang": "painless"
                            },
                            "order": "asc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "outputCol4": {
                "format": "0.000"
                "avg": {
                    "script": {
                        "source": "doc['col4'].value",
                        "lang": "painless"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       }
   }

  }
```

My question:

1. Can I change the decimal points when we query only for certain fields since the output can also contain a non-decimal value like `Integer` and `String`
2. Is there any property in the `Elasticsearch` service level to limit the total number of decimal points in the output or stored field?

Answer (score 1):

I formatted decimal output by **format** attribute (see example bellow)

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 0,
"aggregations": {
    "aggr": {
        "type": "term",
        "field": "type.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
            "myAggr2.value": "desc"
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "myAggr2": {
                "type": "sum",
                "field": "cable_length_attribute"
            }
        }
    },
    "total_myAggr2": {
        "type": "sum_bucket",
        "buckets_path": "aggr>myAggr2",
        "format": "#.##"
    }
},
"types": [
    "cable_feature"
],
"typeQuery": {
    "cable_feature": {
        "type": "bool",
        "must": [
            {
                "type": "matchAll"
            }
        ],
        "should": null,
        "must_not": null
    }
}
```

}